# Барьерная синхронизация в MPI

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mpi

Не работает барьерная синхронизация. Делал это для того чтобы сделать все задания лабораторной работы в одном файле. Вот код:

```
#define TASK(num) MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);\
                  if(rank == 0) printf("\n\nTask %d:\n", num);\
                  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, rc;
    rc = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    TASK(2);
    if (rank == 0)
        printf("Root process : Hello, world\n");
    else
        printf("Slave process : my rank is %d\n", rank);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Вывод получился такой:

> Slave process : my rank is 1
>
> Slave process : my rank is 2
>
> Task 2:
>
> Root process : Hello, world

То есть порядок вывода неверный.

Comment: А что возвращает `MPI_Comm_size` во всех процессах? Есть подозрение, что у Вас что-то напутано в окружении `MPI`, и эти процессы запускаются независимыми, с `"MPI_Comm_size == 1"`.

Comment: Уже решил проблему. Оказывается на английской версии stackoverflow было решение. Там проблема что-то с буферами вывода. Точно не помню, но в целом вывод сам по себе, и поэтому его порядок не гарантируется. Сделал вывод каждого потока в отдельный файл.

Comment: Отлично, это стоит оформить ответом.

Comment: и желатешльно со ссылкой на пример в SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305061/ordering-output-in-mpi

Здесь ответ. Коротко переведу. stdout хранит вывод с разных потоков как попало. Данные с одного потока хранятся правильно, друг за другом, но вот данные разных потоков уже не будут гарантированно храниться в порядке поступления.

Если очень хочется вывести по порядку, то лучше самому выделить один поток для печати и отправлять ему все данные, то есть делать вывод не в нескольких потоках, а только в одном.